# How to query based on string type date in mongodb robo3t console?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

In the mongodb collection, I have a variable DateTimeAsString having value in line of 04-26-2017 11:51:40:445.

When i try to execute something like this
`db.getCollection('collection').find({dateTimeAsString: { "$gte": ISODate("2018-03-05"),"$lte": ISODate("2018-03-06") }})`

It returns 0 documents.

I tried to use $where operator and convert DateTimeAsString to Date,but it is still returning 0 documents.

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({$where : function() {
var date = new Date(this.dateTimeAsString)
var newdate=new Date("2018-03-05 00:00:00");
if (date > newdate)
    return this
}}).count()
```

Note- I want to use this in Robo3t Console.

Thanks.

Comment: Technically your second option should work (it works for me, DB version 3.0.15, Robo 3T 1.1.1), it seems like you just mess with dates. In your exact example your 'dateTimeAsString' is less than 'newdate', but condition is opposite.

Comment: It was just an example date. I am having dates greater than newdate also. Also, i tried to change the condition, Still 0 documents.

Comment: Can you run this code? 

`db.test.insertMany([
    { name:'A', date: '04-26-2017 11:51:40:445'},
    { name:'B', date: '04-26-2018 11:51:40:445'},
    { name:'C', date: '04-26-2018 11:51:40:445'},
    { name:'D', date: '04-26-2017 11:51:40:445'},
])

db.test.find({$where : function() {
    var date = new Date(this.date);
    var newdate = new Date("2018-03-05");
    if (date > newdate)
        return this
}}).count()`

it should return you count 2 (meaning it found 'B' and 'C')

Comment: It is giving 0 for the above also.  Db version-3.4.10

Comment: I was able to repeat your issue on other instance of mongodb server (DB 3.2.16). Either bug in mongodb or problem in server locale and the way it parse date.

Comment: Take a look on this topic with custom date format parsing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313541/convert-string-to-date-or-isodate-using-mongo-shell-in-mongodb maybe it will fit your needs